# Can't connect to Redis instance hosted by GCP Memotystore to my AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, redis, vpn, google-cloud-memorystore

I have created a HPA VPN Tunnel between GCP and AWS with this documentation: [Create HA VPN connections between Google Cloud and AWS](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/tutorials/create-ha-vpn-connections-google-cloud-aws)  as checked I am able to ping the Virtual Machine Hosted in GCP on AWS EC2 instance and vice-versa. Now I have created a Redis instance in the same VPC in which my tunnel is connected. I can able to connect redis on my gcp Virtual Machine but not able to connect on AWS EC2 instance.

Comment: Check if port 6379 is allowed

Comment: Port 6379 is allowed